# how to extract parameter in beanshell

Tags: regex, jmeter, beanshell

How to extract parameter in beanshell. Please give me some example or link. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried something before asking?

Answer (score 0):

I have only used the PostProcessor element 'JSON extractor' to extract a value from a response.  There are other extractor elements in the PostProcessors.  Once you extract the value into a variable, if you need it in another thread group, you can add it to a beanshell to make it a property, for example like this:

```
${__setProperty(clientId, ${clientId})};
```

Then when you need to use the clientId, you would just call it whereever you need like this:

```
${__property(clientId)}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all "usual" recommendation to use JMeter's built-in components where possible and avoid scripting unless it is absolutely required. If it is - consider using [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language as other supported scripting languages have performance issues.

Coming back to your "question":

- What `parameter`? Request parameter? If yes, what is [sampler type](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) and parameter name? Response parameter?
- From which Beanshell test elemenet ([Pre](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor)/[Post Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor), [Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Assertion), [Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Timer), [Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Listener))?

We are not telepathic enough to guess what you are trying to achieve. See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) for general information on Beanshell scripting in JMeter tests and/or elaborate your question providing more details.